# How to step-into outermost function call in the line with LLDB?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, lldb

Let's say I'm debugging code like this

```
   outer(fn1(), fn2());
```

If I use the `s` command, LLDB will first step into `fn1`, then I type `fin` to step-out, `s` again steps into `fn2`, `fin`... and only now I'm able to step-into `outer` which is what I wanted since the beginning.

Is there a way to tell LLDB on which function call to step-in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lldb comes with an alias for exactly this: `sif`. In the given example, you can run:

```
(lldb) sif outer
```

You can remember it as **s**tep **i**nto **f**unction

It works with partial matches, it doesn't have to be called with the full function name. In this case, you could also run `sif out` for example.

Comment: One more trick: type `help` in after entering `lldb` REPL environment, then there is the full list of supported lldb commands, and `sif` is there.

Answer (score 2):

`thread step-in --step-in-target outer` or more compactly, `s -t outer` will stop when it has stepped into `outer`.  See `help s` for the documentation.

Answer (score -3):

Directly No. 
But you can set a break point in definition of outer function.