# What is lldb's equivalent one of gdb's advance command?

Tags: c++, gdb, lldb

When debugging C/C++ function that with many arguments, and each arguments may still call some functions, people have to repeated typing `step` and `finish`, then reach where this function's body part.

e.g. I'm using OpenCV's `solvePnP()` function, it requires many arguments:

```cpp
    solvePnP(v_point_3d,v_point_2d,K,D,R,T);
```

Among which, each argument will be converted from `cv::Mat` to `cv::InputArray`, thus calling a `init()` function.

What I expected is, directly go to where `solvePnP()` implemented, and I'm not interested in each argument type conversion.

Luckily, there is `advance` command in gdb. Official document is [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html)， writes:

> advance location
>
> Continue running the program up to the given location. An argument is required, which should be of one of the forms described in Specify Location. Execution will also stop upon exit from the current stack frame. This command is similar to until, but advance will not skip over recursive function calls, and the target location doesn’t have to be in the same frame as the current one.

**This gdb `advance` command really helps. And what's the equivalent command in LLDB?**

I've search in lldb official's gdb => lldb command mapping web page, https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html , but not found.

---

Edit: I forgot to mention, the gdb usage for me is

```
(gdb) b main
(gdb) r
(gdb) advance solvePnP
```

Comment: Checkout the `sif` command for lldb. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56436965/how-to-step-into-outermost-function-call-in-the-line-with-lldb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the `sif` command for lldb. `sif` means **Step **I**nto **F**unction

Reference: [How to step-into outermost function call in the line with LLDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56436965/how-to-step-into-outermost-function-call-in-the-line-with-lldb)

To get all the supported commands of LLDB, one should first go into lldb command, then type `help`, then there will be the explanations for `sif`:

> sif       -- Step through the current block, stopping if you step directly into a function whose name matches the TargetFunctionName.